# How to add an xml file in a sever path

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an XML file that I want to add to my server each time the user has finished his action.
I read that it was enough that I add in the web config, appSettings with a value as the path of my address, but unfortunately every time I am fit I am told that the Uri format is not recognized.
I am new in the field. Would there be a welcome help?

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="Path" value="http://sp1051test:8080/include/"/>
</appSettings>
```

And in my method, I have done this :

```
string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"].ToString();
file.TheDocument.Save(filePath + file.Nom + "_" + file.Type + ".xml");
```

Comment: What is the type of `file`? What is the exact exception you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

You only put the relative path in config file there not full path,because everu time your application will not be running on `sp1051test:8080`, as path can change on the IIS, so save relative url in config file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="Path" value="~/include/"/>
</appSettings>
```

and in Code Behind use [`Server.MapPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to create absolute url:

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"].ToString()+ file.Nom + "_" + file.Type + ".xml");

file.TheDocument.Save(filePath);
```

Comment: Richard, the type of file is just a class (my object). Ehksan, when you just put "~/include/", how it can recognize that it has to put it in the location of the server (mine) ?

Comment: @JoëlMulaj'i appllication is running on serve so it is obvious that file will be saved on server and the **~** means root directory of your application

Comment: Ehsan, when I tried, it says that he can not find a path with that location. It seems that he tried to find it in local disk.                        "Could not find a part of the path 'c:\users\tshimaj\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Editeur_Entete_Marge\Editeur_Entete_Marge\include\Testing Quotidien_Marge.xml'." that's the message

Comment: it is the location where you application resides, if you check your soultion is in this directory, is'nt it? and @JoëlMulaj'i do you have include folder in this direcotry, make sure : **c:\users\tshimaj\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Editeur_Entete_Marge\Editeur_Entete_Marge**

Comment: That's what i was saying. I dont want it to go to my c:\users\tshimaj\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Editeur_Entete_Marge\Editeur_Entete_Marge. I want it to go directly to the server (for test) , which is "sp1051test....." and in that location there's a file named include

Comment: @JoëlMulaj'i your application is in some directory IIS just maps it to the **sp1051test:8080** si when you say file to store on server it will be stored where your application resides